# Resolve by key or by type

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

What is preferred option of component resolution with castle windsor IoC container: Resolve by type or resolve by key or by type and key?

What is differences?

In which situatuation should I use one approach and in which others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not resolve at all. Well, actually let me rephrase - [you should only resolve once](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Three-Calls-Pattern.ashx).

When you resolve, 99% of the time you will just specify the type - "I want an `IFoo`". That makes things simpler and more flexible.

Cases where you do want to resolve by name are usually when you have multiple components for a given service and you want an instance of a single, non-default component. One particular scenario is in multi-tenant applications where you have component per tenant.

Comment: "You should not resolve at all." yea, I know that I shouldn't manually resolve components, but question is not about this. Question is about when this feature would be useful. Thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: Just making sure the answer is explicit, for the next guy